# Tkinter Button States

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I'm writing a program that switches on  a series of LEDs. When the code is executed, it opens a GUI that has a series of buttons. When the Raspberry Pi is connected to the GPIO board, 1 LED switches on and then switches off.

I'm trying to introduce a state system for the buttons stating that when a button is pressed, this happens and when its pressed again it switches off. I tried to implement something in my 'if statement' but I'm not sure about how to actually implement it.

for example if buttonPressed == true
(led on code)

buttonPressed (pressed again)

(led off code)

This is my code so far

```
    b1 = Button(self, text ="io_1", command = self.send_signal)
    b1.config(height = 1, width = 10)
    b1.place(x =80, y = 150)

    b2 = Button(self, text ="io_2", command = self.send_signal)
    b2.config(height = 1, width = 10)
    b2.place(x =160, y = 150)
```

These are the buttons. I've already done the screen initialtition like root = tk().

```
    def send_signal(self): #This is the function for the funtionality for the button
    print("sending Signal")


try:
        ledState = False
        if ledState == False:

            GPIO.output(LEDPin, True)
            print("LED ON")
            ledState = True
            sleep(1)

        elif ledState == True:
            GPIO.output(LEDPin, False)
            print("LED OFF")
            ledState = False
            sleep(0.5)
```

The code above is the code for the buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a general logic question as it is applicable to anything really!

You need to set a flag each time the button is pressed using the IF that you mentioned. If the flag is currently false, set it to true; if it is true, set it to false. Here is a general solution.

```
from time import sleep

toggle_state = False

while True:
    if toggle_state:
        print("Currently True")
        toggle_state = False
    else:
        print("Currently False")
        toggle_state = True
    sleep(1)
```

Regarding your specific solution, I would suggest a slight alteration as follows;

```
def send_signal(self): #This is the function for the funtionality for the button
    print("sending Signal")


    ledState = False

    if ledState:
        GPIO.output(LEDPin, False)
        print("LED OFF")
        ledState = False
    else:
        GPIO.output(LEDPin, True)
        print("LED ON")
        ledState = True
    sleep(1)
```

Side note;

- `sleep` pauses the entire program, which will make the GUI feel like it has hung.
- The `try` block is too broad and requires exceptions, plus I do not think it is necessary anyway.